# How to extract text from HTML label using BeautifulSoup (Python)?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a Python script that goes out and interacts with some HTML. I'm currently using BeautifulSoup to parse this HTML (I've used it before with XML and it's AWESOME!!!) and I'm wondering what's the best way to extract the time (text) information from the HTML. Here's a picture of what I'm talking about below:

I'm trying to extract the "Room 225 8:00am" , "Room 225 8:30am", etc...

Does anyone have a specific recommendation for a BeautifulSoup function that works for extracting text from a label?

[image]

Here's also the raw HTML (prettified):

```
<html>
 <body>
  <li class="zone even open day">
   <label for="srr-1-1397046600">
    Room 225 8:30 AM
   </label>
   <input id="srr-1-1397046600" name="srr-1-1397046600" type="checkbox" value="Y"/>
   <span class="drag-handle">
   </span>
  </li>
  ,
  <li class="zone even open day">
   <label for="srr-1-1397050200">
    Room 225 9:30 AM
   </label>
   <input id="srr-1-1397050200" name="srr-1-1397050200" type="checkbox" value="Y"/>
   <span class="drag-handle">
   </span>
  </li>
  ,
  <li class="zone even open day">
   <label for="srr-1-1397053800">
    Room 225 10:30 AM
   </label>
   <input id="srr-1-1397053800" name="srr-1-1397053800" type="checkbox" value="Y"/>
   <span class="drag-handle">
   </span>
  </li>
  ,
  <li class="zone even open day">
   <label for="srr-1-1397057400">
    Room 225 11:30 AM
   </label>
   <input id="srr-1-1397057400" name="srr-1-1397057400" type="checkbox" value="Y"/>
   <span class="drag-handle">
   </span>
  </li>
  ,
  <li class="zone even open day">
   <label for="srr-1-1397068200">
    Room 225 2:30 PM
   </label>
   <input id="srr-1-1397068200" name="srr-1-1397068200" type="checkbox" value="Y"/>
   <span class="drag-handle">
   </span>
  </li>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do post the *HTML text* instead of a screenshot; it makes it so much easier to provide you with a demo.

Comment: And [`element.string`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) was not working for you? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I tried putting in the raw HTML, however, stack overflow keeps reading it as real HTML. I haven't tried element.string, let me try that.

Comment: Use the `{}` to indent all lines with 4 leading spaces. See [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)

Answer (score 6):

Search for the `label` elements, then use the [`element.string` attribute](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) to get the label text.

Here, perhaps a [CSS selector search](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) is helpful:

```
for label in soup.select('li.zone label'):
    print label.string
```

Demo:

```
>>> for label in soup.select('li.zone label'):
...     print label.string
... 
Room 225 8:30 AM
Room 225 9:30 AM
Room 225 10:30 AM
Room 225 11:30 AM
Room 225 2:30 PM
```

Comment: Quick question... why are BeautifulSoup functions only limited to work with "soup." instead of any variable? Such as var = soup.findAll(id='student') And then do var.prettify()

Comment: But `findAll()` *returns a list of results*. So you'd do `var[0].prettify()`.

Comment: If you used `var = soup.find(id='student')` instead you'd get the first match (logical for a search by ID), and you'd get just one element object.